# Java BufferedReader reads two lines only

Tags: java, bufferedreader

So I have this Void function that is suppose to read integers from a .txt file and it works for the most part except it only reads the first two lines I've tried everything to my power and nothing seems to work

```
public static void load(Player p) {
       String line = "";
        String token = "";
        String token2 = "";
        String[] token3 = new String[3];
        boolean EndOfFile = false;
        BufferedReader characterfile = null;
        boolean File1 = false;

        try {
            characterfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./cache/Player.txt"));
            File1 = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileex1) {
        }

        if (File1) {
            // new File ("./characters/"+playerName+".txt");
        } else {
            System.out.println("character file not found.");
        }
        try {
            line = characterfile.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ioexception) {
            System.out.println(": error loading file.");
        }
        while (EndOfFile == false && line != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            int spot = line.indexOf("=");
            if (spot > -1) {
                token = line.substring(0, spot);
                token = token.trim();
                token2 = line.substring(spot + 1);
                token2 = token2.trim();
                token3 = token2.split("\t");
                 if (token.equals("Difficulty")) {
                    Player.setDifficulty(Integer.parseInt(token2));
                }
                        else if (token.equals("Player Health")) {
                                //System.out.println(token2);
                            System.out.println("debug");
                                Player.setHealth(Integer.parseInt(token2));
                            }
                        else  if (token.equals("Player Strength")) {
                                //System.out.println(token2);
                                Player.setStrength(Integer.parseInt(token2));
                            }
                        try {
                            line = characterfile.readLine();
                        } catch (IOException ioexception1) {
                            System.out.println("sent");
                            EndOfFile = true;
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        characterfile.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioexception) {
                    }
        }
        }
```

this is my save method which functions as intended.

```
public void save(Player p) {
    BufferedWriter characterfile = null;
    try {
        characterfile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./cache/Player.txt"));
        characterfile.write("Player Strength = ");
        characterfile.write(Integer.toString(Player.getStrength()));
        characterfile.newLine();
        characterfile.write("Player Health = ");
        characterfile.write(Integer.toString(Player.getHealth()));
        characterfile.newLine();
        characterfile.write("Difficulty = ");
        characterfile.write(Integer.toString(Player.getDifficulty()));
        characterfile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is what my Player.txt Looks like

```
Player Strength = 0
Player Health = 0
Difficulty = 0
```

again as i said Player Strength and Player Health will be read but then the token won't even go to Difficulty or will completely skip it, I am completely out of ideas.

Comment: for a start never just swallow up exceptions `} catch (FileNotFoundException fileex1) {
        }`

Comment: I think you close the file after reading the second line. But the code is very hard to read. Please format them and repost it.

Comment: put this `characterfile.close();` line outside of `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close the file in the while loop.

move these lines:

```
try {
  characterfile.close();
} catch (IOException ioexception) {
}
```

add a `}' before the lines and remove one after.

Comment: And of curse: Add a log statement in the catch- block.

Comment: This fixed it I didn't even notice that my loop closed the file man i feel silly thank you so much.

Comment: @user3404907 If you format your code better, you can see it better ;)

Answer (score 1):

Call to `br.readLine()` will only read one line at a time.You can loop until `br.readLine()` not return `null`.

```
String line=null;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
//Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you call `characterfile.close();` in your loop. This should be outside your loop (`while (EndOfFile == false && line != null) { ...}`). First loop works but you close you file, second loop you get IOException because you are trying to read your closed file.